# Extra error-like characters in the output

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to iterate over `movies` array with my `thumbs_up` method and print it to screen.

```
class Movie
  def initialize(title,rank)
    @title=title
    @rank=rank
  end
  def thumbs_up
    @rank+=1
  end
  def to_s
    puts "your title is #{@title.to_s} and its rank is #{@rank.to_s} "
  end
end

movie1 = Movie.new("Goonies", 6)
movie2 = Movie.new("Spun", 3)
movie3 = Movie.new("Hook", 2)
movies = [movie1, movie2, movie3]
movies.each do |x|
  puts x.thumbs_up
  puts x
end
```

I'm getting extra error like characters after the output. This is the output that is mostly right but contains extra thing after my desired input:

```
your title is Goonies and its rank is 7 
#<Movie:0x007fa6ba0e1da8>
4
your title is Spun and its rank is 4 
#<Movie:0x007fa6ba0e1d58>
3
your title is Hook and its rank is 3 
#<Movie:0x007fa6ba0e1d08>
```

What do I need to alter or remove it?

Answer (score 3):

The output you're referring to isn't actually 'error-like characters'. It's an object. One method is to remove the `puts` from the `to_s` method, however it's generally considered bad practice to override it other than to modify its immediate representation (e.g., outputting something in a certain format versus outputting it as part of a sentence). A better, more modular approach would be as follows:

```
class Movie
  def initialize(title,rank)
    @title = title
    @rank = rank
  end

  def thumbs_up
    @rank+=1
  end

  def thumbs_down
    @rank-=1
  end

  attr_reader :title, :rank
  attr_accessor :title
end

movie1 = Movie.new("Goonies",6)
movie2 = Movie.new("Spun",3)
movie3 = Movie.new("Hook",2)
movies = [movie1 ,movie2, movie3]

movies.each do |x|
  x.thumbs_up
  puts "Your title is #{x.title} and its rank is #{x.rank}"
end
```

This outputs the following:

```
Your title is Goonies and its rank is 7
Your title is Spun and its rank is 4
Your title is Hook and its rank is 3
```

This works by utilising the attributes you made public via the `attr_reader` statement within the `Movie` class.

Comment: `to_s` is *meant* to be overridden, it is absolutely not a bad practice if it makes sense; for example, `Complex` defines its own `to_s`, overriding `Numeric#to_s`, since you want the complex numbers to say `(3i+2)` and not something like `<#Complex:0x007fe86c01d9a0 @real=2, @imaginary=3>`. In case of movies, `def to_s; "#{title} (#{year})"; end` would make sense, as this is how movies are most often printed. Even `def to_s; "#{title} (##{rank})"; end` would make sense. But I agree it does not make sense to put in a whole English sentence there; that's better done with an outside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `puts` from the `to_s` method.